# Error building CNN train module

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, tensorflow, keras

while training the CNN(ShallowNet) with my own custom data with 4 classes but am getting this error on model.fit function:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "train_network.py", line 98, in 
>       epochs=args["epochs"], verbose=args["verbose"])
>    ....
>   ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_2 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (373, 4)

Here I guess the issue is with train label array shape,

But before that let me tell you how i loaded the data and label arrya's

```
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    # load the image, pre-process it, and store it in the data list
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (32, 32))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    data.append(image)

    # extract the class label from the image path and update the
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
    labels.append(int(label))
```

After that formated the array and split the train and test data:

```
trainData = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)

(_, testData, _, testLabels) = train_test_split(trainData,
                                            labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

testLabels = to_categorical(testLabels, num_classes=len(np.unique(testLabels)))

trainLabels = to_categorical(labels, num_classes=len(np.unique(labels)))
```

after that started compiling the model and passed the appropriate parameters, as per the post:

```
model = ConvNetFactory.build(args["network"], 3, 32, 32,
len(np.unique(trainLabels)),**kargs)

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=sgd, metrics=["accuracy"])
```

then started training by providing trainX and trainY to fit function:

```
model.fit(trainData, trainLabels, batch_size=args["batch_size"],
      epochs=args["epochs"], verbose=args["verbose"])
```

but at this line it throws the error, mentioned earlier, also following is the code block from convnetfactory class:

```
    def ShallowNet(numChannels, imgRows, imgCols, numClasses, **kwargs):
        # initialzie the model
        model = Sequential()

        # define the first (and only) CONV => RELU layer
        model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode="same",
                            input_shape=(imgRows, imgCols, numChannels)))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))

        # add a FC layer followed by the soft-max classifier
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(numClasses))
        model.add(Activation("softmax"))

        # return the network architecture
        return model
```

here in this function i have just made input_shape to channel later, also i tried by interchanging the

```
loss = sparse_categorical_crossentropy
```

instead of

```
loss = categorical_crossentropy
```

but that also not worked, also these are the shapes of my traindata and label data:

trainLabels.shape ==> (373, 4)
and 
trainData.shape ==> (373, 32, 32, 3)

The keras version am using is 2.0.6

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @U.Swap, Can you please tell me what is the value of numClasses passed as the parameter to the ShallowNet function?

Comment: its 4 , as the no. of classes in dataset is 4

Comment: Please include the output of model.summary(), it will tell us if the model was built correctly and if the parameters are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works fine with

```
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=sgd, metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I am not sure about the usage of "sparse_categorical_cross_entropy", but I think you need to have one output that is the class ID,in the output layer, to be used (hence expecting a [None, 1] array).

Here is the full code that I used for testing, including initialization of training data using random values:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
import random

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras import backend as K

imgRows = 32
imgCols = 32
numChannels = 3
numClasses = 4

# create random training data
trainData = np.zeros((373,32,32,3), np.float)
trainLabels = np.zeros((373,4), np.uint)

# initialize data randomly
for i in range(0,373):
    # set training data
    for p in range(0, 32):
        for q in range(0,32):
            for r in range(0,3):
                trainData[p,q,r] = np.random.ranf()
    # set a class label
    randLabel = random.randint(0,3)
    trainLabels[i,randLabel] = 1

# initialzie the model
model = Sequential()
# define the first (and only) CONV => RELU layer
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), border_mode="same", activation = 'relu',
                            input_shape=(imgRows, imgCols, numChannels)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
# add a FC layer followed by the soft-max classifier
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(numClasses))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

model.summary() 
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)    
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=sgd, metrics=["accuracy"])   
print K.image_data_format()  
model.fit(trainData, trainLabels, batch_size=8, epochs=100)
```

Comment: trainLabels[randLabel] = 1 here is a dictionary collection,but numpy array required.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, edited the code to make it trainLabels[i,randLabel] = 1. Fortunately, this only affected training, for which you have actual data.

Comment: I guess what you have mentioned is done by to_categorical function itself, but i tried it by pre-defining the label array shape with 7 classes, but now it throws:  ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 574 input samples and 4018 target samples.

Comment: 4018 is 574*7. Do check if the target label array is 4018x1 instead of 574x7. I avoided using to_categorical because using another library just adds more complexity when it comes to explaining things.